# Working with window function in SQLITE

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this set of data

```
purchasingid          date   supplierid
1                2014-01-01    12
2                2014-01-01    13
3                2013-12-06    12
4                2013-12-05    11
5                2014-01-01    17
6                2013-12-05    12
```

I want to check for all suppliers who bought on 2014-01-01 what was the date of their previous order. If it doesn't exists leave it blank.

meaning I want to get:

```
supplierid   date   last_time_buy_date
12            2014-01-01   2013-12-06
13            2014-01-01  
17            2014-01-01
```

supplierid 11 did not buy on 2014-01-01 so he does not appear at all.

This is what I did:

```
select supplierid,date, max(date)
from purchasing 
where supplierid in (select supplierid
                     from purchasing
                     where date='2014-01-01')
```

This doesnt work. I know I should use window function somehow but I don't know how to... Any thoughts?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten that you can  ***accept*** an (excellent) answer

Answer (score 5):

SQLite doesn't support window functions.  Instead, you can do:

```
select p.*,
       (select max(p2.date)
        from purchasing p2
        where p2.supplierid = p.supplierid and
              p2.date < p.date
       ) as prev_date
from purchasing p
where p.date = '2014-01-01';
```

Comment: Thanks. However some customers has two rows in your query (if supplier has two orders on 2014-01-01)

Comment: Can we change  p.date = '2014-01-01'; to be the minimum(date)? so if we have more than one record in this date it will be the minimal?

Comment: @jack . . . I don't fully understand what you mean.  You can use a subquery to get the minimum date in the `where` clause.  If that doesn't answer the question in your comment, then ask *another* question.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite will probably support window functions starting with version 3.25. The documentation for that is at https://www.sqlite.org/draft/windowfunctions.html.