# Is there a name for this method?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table of orders of a e-shop like

| user_id | created_at | delivered_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcd21f | 2020-02-04 08:09:04 | 2020-02-05 17:28:59 |
| vhw1wd2 | 2020-02-05 12:59:49 | 2020-02-07 08:50:35 |

The task is to find avg time between the first delivery and creation of next order by every user. It would be easy with window functions but sqlite 2.6.0 lacks these.
I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588120/working-with-window-function-in-sqlite) thread with an offer to replace window functions with structure like

```
select p.*,
       (select max(p2.date)
        from purchasing p2
        where p2.supplierid = p.supplierid and
              p2.date < p.date
       ) as prev_date
from purchasing p
where p.date = '2014-01-01';
```

(obv this code is not for my table)
I've made some progress using similar construction but I am unable to progress until I find out exactly the way it works.
What's this `FROM table t` that creates there t1 t2 etc tables or where to read about it?

Comment: table works on preview but not in the post idk why but it doesn't matter much

Comment: I've fixed the table formatting, you needed a line break before the table for it to format properly. I'm not sure why the preview didn't reflect that.

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is interpreted as follows :
***Select all rows in the purchasing table provided the date is '2014-01-01'.***

```
select p.*
from purchasing p
where p.date = '2014-01-01';
```

then , the internal select clause is executed once for each row of the above query record. That is, go to the purchasing table where supplierid is equal to the current row of supplierid And the date is smaller than the current row date Then, with the said conditions, give me the row that has the most date.

```
(select max(p2.date)
 from purchasing p2
 where p2.supplierid = p.supplierid and
      p2.date < p.date
 ) as prev_date
```